# Paste to Original Coordinates problem in AutoCAD Map 2012

Tags: autocad-map

I have a problem copy-pasting from a drawing to another blank drawing to a same coordinate position. Here's what I have done:

1. Selected the shape I wanted to copy, a simple rectangle
   representing land parcel.
2. Clicked "copy".
3. Start a new blank using ctrl+N
4. Clicked dropdown below "paste" and choosed "paste to original coordinates"
5. At this point Cad used to be automatically zoom to full extent to the shape I was copied, but today it is suddenly not. So I used zoom command and selected Extent.
6. The result was a random polylines completely different to what I have copied previously, in a random position/coordinates.

I have reinstalled my AutoCAD but no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1- make a copy of file, open new file and delete everything else except what you need.

2- Export into shapefile (by selecting what you need) and import from shapefile

3- start a new blank ACAD and create a point with coordinates (at both DWGs), than copy and paste with base point (by choosing as reference that point which is in both DWGs)

I'm sure that there are more solution than reinstalling the software.

Comment: Although, Autodesk is not a crappy company, you could ask support if you think that there is an issue just for you.